# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am getting this error when I build my project that involves posting to Facebook from an iPhone: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've gotten errors like this before and it's always been because I have failed to import some package. But, I have already imported "FBConnect.h" and "Facebook.h", but maybe there's another one I'm missing. I also saw on a post on this site that you need to put the FBConnectSDK framework in "Link Binary With Libraries" under Build Settings, but I did that and I got 13 more errors... I am using storyboard and ARC is set to off. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I finally fixed it. After a hail mary google search i found that i needed to import the FacebookSDK file into the AppDelegate.h file, and then I needed to delete all the code in one of the two FBRequest files that I had in my project, which didn't work until about the 6th time I tried it

Answer (score 2):

I solve a similar problem by checking the Target Membership of my library.
Select the library and files relevant to your app target from the Navigator. Check on the Utilities section that those files are marked as required for your app target.